# Display raw HTML using WebGrid in ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, razor-grid

I have a grid like this:

```
WebGrid grid = new WebGrid(source: Model, rowsPerPage: 5, ajaxUpdateContainerId: "GridContainer");
```

Now, I want to display "MyContent" column as raw [HTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML). What should I do?

```
<div id="GridContainer">
    @grid.GetHtml(columns:
        grid.Columns(
            grid.Column(
                columnName: "MyContent",
                //Format: What should I put here?
            )
        )
    )
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use

```
<div id="GridContainer">
    @grid.GetHtml(columns:
        grid.Columns(
            grid.Column(
                columnName: "MyContent",
                format: (item) =>
                    {
                       var links = Html.ActionLink("Edit",   "Edit",    new {id = item.PrimaryKey})  + " | " +
                                   Html.ActionLink("Details","Details", new { id = item.PrimaryKey}) + " | "+
                                   Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete",  new { id = item.PrimaryKey});

                       return Html.Raw(links);
                    }
                )
            )
        )
```

which renders as

```
<td>
    <a href="/Home/Edit/5">Edit</a> |
    <a href="/Home/Details/5">Details</a> |
    <a href="/Home/Delete/5">Delete</a>
</td>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But what if I just want to render all of its content as raw Html? It's just a paragraph with tag formatted.

Comment: format:(item)=> Html.Raw(item) , u will get html text for the item

Comment: No, what I get is `RuntimeBinderException` with message `The best overloaded method match for 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper.Raw(string)' has some invalid arguments`. I think `item` here is not a string.

Comment: Oh, I've found the solution. I should have written `item.{my property name}`, just simple. Thanks for your help :D

Answer (score 0):

I think it is much cleaner to use the annotations in the model.

```
[GridColumn(Title="&nbsp;", SanitizeEnabled=false,EncodeEnabled=false)]
    public IHtmlString RateLink
    {
        get{
            return new HtmlString("<a href=\"" + BaseUrl + Id + "\" target=\"_blank\">Open</a>");
        }
    }
```

If you use only annotations your html only needs:

```
@Html.Grid(Model).AutoGenerateColumns()
```