# MVC grid.Column with bootstrap glyphicon not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I wanna a show a bootstrap glyphicon in a MVC4 Webgrid Column. This is not showing anything:

```
    grid.Column("Enabled", "ENABLED", canSort: true, format: item => item.Enabled ?
                Html.Raw("<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok></span>'") :
                Html.Raw("<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-nok></span>'")),
```

Any idea of how can I make this work ?

Rds.

Comment: Can you get it to work with just static HTML and the bootstrap css included?  A jsfiddle might be nice to show an example

Comment: I may be wrong but jsfiddle does not support MVC WebGrid.<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok></span> alone works pretty well. Check out [This](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#glyphicons).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Display raw Html using WebGrid in MVC3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14330330/display-raw-html-using-webgrid-in-mvc3)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample code to bind image to html mvc grid, instead of span you can use

```
@Html.Grid(Model).Columns(columns =>
{
   columns.Add().Encoded(false).Sanitized(false).RenderValueAs(o => @<a class="your class" href='/#/@(o.Id !=null ? o.Id : 1)'><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" data-unicode="270f"></span></a>).Titled("Enable");
}).WithPaging(15).Sortable(true).SetRowCssClasses(item => item.Enabled != null ? "enabledUser" : "disabledUser").Named("globalGrid")
```